# Obtaining the predicates in a Lambda Calculus Expression

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, lambda-calculus

What would be the code to obtain the predicate in a given lambda calculus expression.

Given the lambda expression

```
(race(x) & run(I2,x))
```

I know that race and run are predicates.

How would I extract out the predicates in the code or any given code?

Comment: You might look at [pyparsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) if you can distill your "any given code" into a grammar.

Comment: I originally got my lambda calculus expression from and FCFG grammar so would that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org), you can re-use their parser (assuming your expressions are strings):

```
import nltk

read_expr = nltk.sem.Expression.fromstring

teststr = '(race(x) & run(I2,x))'

parsed = read_expr(teststr)
for p in parsed.predicates():
    print(p)
```